# entering Canada without US passport

Tags: passports, canada, borders

I know that technically it's possible to do so using only a birth certificate and US drivers license. However there is a difference between what is technically possible and what happens in practice, so my question is has anyone done this recently? I only ask because my passport won't be here for a few weeks and was hoping to enter Canada and just have a family member FedEx it to my friend's house there. So has anyone tried it recently or know anyone who has?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to my eyes, but feel free to flag it or comment if I've linked it in error. Thanks!

Comment: I was more or less looking for recent info on the matter, since things tend to change on the ground quickly.